# what is the difference between ls -a and ls -A command

Tags: linux, shell-script, ls

```
$ ls -a
 .                .cache      final        .lesshst          .pki              
.sh_history                 .wget-hsts
 ..               .config     .gnome       .local            .presage          
.sudo_as_admin_successful   .Xauthority
.audacity-data   .dbus       .gnupg       .mozilla          .profile          
Templates                   .xscreensaver
.bash_history    Desktop     .gphoto      Music             Public           'Unix 
programs'              .xsession-errors
.bash_logout     Documents   .idlerc      .password-store   .python_history   Videos
.bashrc          Downloads  'Ise notes'   Pictures          scripts           
.viminfo


$ ls -A
.audacity-data   .config     final    'Ise notes'   .password-store   Public                      
Templates        .Xauthority
.bash_history    .dbus       .gnome    .lesshst     Pictures          .python_history            
'Unix programs'   .xscreensaver
.bash_logout     Desktop     .gnupg    .local       .pki              scripts                     
Videos           .xsession-errors
.bashrc          Documents   .gphoto   .mozilla     .presage          .sh_history                 
.viminfo                          
.cache           Downloads   .idlerc   Music        .profile          
.sudo_as_admin_successful   .wget-hsts
```

Answer (score 2):

Both print all files and directories including hidden ones (those starting with dot), the only difference is that `-A` doesn't print `.` and `..` for current and parent directories. See [ls man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) for more details:

> -a, --all
>
> do not ignore entries starting with .

> -A, --almost-all
>
> do not list implied . and ..